# check board diagonally right c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm doing a reversi board game. Basically you have player X and player O, when player X 'traps' player O token in the middle of two of his token, player O token is 'flipped' over and become Player X instead.

So basically I got the other checks semi-working. But for the life of me I can't get the diagonal right.

So for the diagonal left I used a two variables for loop in order to count and make it work.

i.e.

```
for(i=r-2, j=c-2;j>=0;i--,j--)
```

But because when I check diagonally to the right(lets say I start from bottom left). The row is decreasing while the column is increasing, and AFAIK the two variables for loop doesn't handle that(?).

Thanks!

Comment: Show us the code.  When you used debugger, what line failed?

Comment: Have you tried using graph or quadrille paper and pencil?

Comment: Yeah I drew it out and know what I want to do, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which way your coordinate system is oriented, but you can do the following if it helps:

```
for(i=r-2, j=c-2;j>=0;i++,j--)
```

That is, you are allowed to increment one index and decrement another one in the same for statement.

To test both conditions:

```
for(i=r-2, j=c-2;j>=0 && i<MAX;i++,j--)
```

Comment: I don't understand this, I'm checking diagonally to the right so i'm starting from bottom left. In a 5x5 table this would be coordinates (5,1). With (1,1) being the top left corner.

I understand the increasing one and decreasing the other part in the same statement, however what about the bounds? AFAIK it only takes on the 2nd bound you give it, in this case 'j'. Therefore, I have one that is in danger of reaching 0 while the other is reaching the MAX, how would I control this?

Comment: @user2963379 you could use '&&' operator in the condition part.

Answer (score 0):

Example on looping diagonally from bottom-left to top-right.

```
for ( i = col, j = row; j >= 0 && i < SIZE; i++, j-- )
```